# Testing closures. How to test a callback passed to a closure jasmine

Tags: javascript, callback, jasmine, closures

I am working through closure challenges in a course on frontendmasters.com led by Will Sentance. I'm struggling to test my functionality.

This function `after` takes the number of times the callback needs to be called before being executed as the first parameter and the callback as the second parameter.

Here is my solution.

```
function closures() {
  // more functions above...
  this.after = (r, cb) => {
    counter = 1;
    return () => { if (counter == r) cb() } ;
  };
}
```

Here are my specs

```
describe("Closure", () => {
  beforeEach( () =>{
    closure = new closures();
  });

  describe('after', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      hello = () => console.log('hello');
      spyOn(console, 'log');
      runOnce = closure.after(3, hello);
    });

    it("executes callback after called first x times", () => {
      first = runOnce();
      second = runOnce();
      third = runOnce();
      expect(first).toEqual(undefined); //successfull
      expect(second).toEqual(undefined);  // successful
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');  // successful
      expect(console.log.calls.count()).toEqual(1);  // fails expected 0 to eq 1
    })
  });
}

Please advise how to test the callback is only invoked once.
```

Comment: Try creating a spy directly rather than spying on console log? `jasmine.createSpy`

Comment: If `cb` is not a function that comes in as a parameter to that `closures` function (or maybe from the outer scope) than there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit testing solution:

`closures.js`:

```js
function closures() {
  this.after = (r, cb) => {
    counter = 1;
    return () => {
      if (counter == r) cb();
    };
  };
}

module.exports = closures;
```

`closures.test.js`:

```js
const closures = require('./closures');

fdescribe('Closure', () => {
  let closure;
  const hello = () => console.log('hello');

  beforeEach(() => {
    closure = new closures();
  });

  describe('after', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      spyOn(console, 'log');
    });

    it('executes callback after called first x times', () => {
      const runOnce = closure.after(1, hello);
      const first = runOnce();
      expect(first).toEqual(undefined);
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
      expect(console.log.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    });
    it('should not call calback if counter is not equal with r', () => {
      const runOnce = closure.after(2, hello);
      const first = runOnce();
      expect(first).toEqual(undefined);
      expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 2 of 5 (skipped 3) SUCCESS (0.04 secs / 0.004 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS

src/stackoverflow/59790114 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  closures.js               |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  closures.test.js          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am in time but for those looking for a generic solution: you need a "generating function". The idea is to create a function that produces/returns a closure with a given context passed in. Here is a simple example in JS:

```
const generatingFunc = (context) => {
    return (inc) => {
        console.log("I am a closure logging the context... or updating a storage maybe! The context is: ", context)
        
        return context + inc // or maybe no return
    }
}

const context = 133
const callback = generatingFunc(context)
const inc = 67
const result = callback(inc)

console.log("The result must be " + (context + inc) + " and here it is: ", result)
```

And a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsdjknmf/1/

Then you simply test the generating function's product and call its result if needed